# Can I place an image on a <tr> tag?

Tags: html, css, image

Can I place a background image using CSS on a `<tr>` tag? Will this background image show across all browsers?

Comment: did you try `tr { background-image: url(images/my-background.jpg); }`? (And the only known problems with a TR background were back in FF1/IE6 days (though I'm sure someone else can confirm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> &nbsp; </td>
        <td> &nbsp; </td>
        <td> &nbsp; </td>
        <td> &nbsp; </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table { 
    width:300px; 
    height:200px; 
    border:3px solid blue;
}

tr {
    background-image:url(http://dummyimage.com/300x200/f00/000);
    display: block;  
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Jk5BE/5/

Source: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44361

For this to work, you have to set the row height. In my demo, I've set it to 100%, because there is only one row in my table. If you have multiple row, set the height of the row to the height of the background-image.

Comment: Unfortunately the background image gets repeated. http://jsfiddle.net/Jk5BE/2/ Do you know a way around this?

Comment: @rcravens I didn't know that a background defined for the TR applies to every TD individually. Hm, there might be a solution out there...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  And it'll show on all modern browsers.

You can either use the background attribute or do it with CSS.

If you're using it for HTML emails, then it won't show in Outlook 2007 or later, as they use Microsoft Word as the rendering engine.  Why?  God knows.  But they do.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky. It looks to me like the background image applied in CSS to a tr element gets repeated on each table cell *even if you say don't repeat*. So if the image isn't a simple gradient with right to left symmetry, you may not get what you expect. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Bx998/1/

HTML

```
<table id="tbl1">

    <tr>
        <td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td><td>four</td><td>five</td><td>size</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td><td>four</td><td>five</td><td>size</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

CSS

```
#tbl1 tr{
     background: transparent url('http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png') no-repeat;
}
#tbl1 tr td{
  padding: 5px;
    height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #888;  
}
#tbl1 tr td:first-child{
 padding: 0 0 0 50px;   
}
```

Comment: It's your CSS - #tbl1 tr:first-child { background:.... } would give you ONE image on the first row of a table. Your example is applying that background to every instance of the TR tag. fyi

Comment: @Dawson - I purposely applied the css to every row. However, the image is being repeated in every cell AND the image origin is reset.

Comment: I may have found the solution [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44361). I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Sime Vidas - That is indeed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Just read that bulletin. I was not aware of that. Surprising "bug". It doesn't even make sense...maybe it's an unpublicized 'feature'